# Android: Espresso: Can't run Espresso test with WireMock - org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures

Tags: android, android-espresso, wiremock

Can't build android proejct with WireMock lib

Android Studio 3.2, Android 6.0

I want to add WireMock in my Espresso test.

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.7"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

    implementation project(':common')

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'

    androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0") 

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AddTraderActivityTest {
    @get:Rule
    var wireMockRule = WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8081))

 @Test
    fun toolBarHeight() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolBar)).check(matches(withHeightResId(R.dimen.tool_bar_height)))
    }
```

But when I try to start this Espresso test I get error:

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:386)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
```

Comment: Did you get to achieve